# Listview with one column that is combobox

Tags: c#, .net, listview, combobox

I'm trying to get my ListView to contain one column that is a ComboBox. I'm adding multiple entries to the list on startup. One of the columns is "Versions". There can be multiple versions and I want to give the user the opportunity to choose which version of the item he/she wants to update to.

Current ListView :

```
lv_requirements.CheckBoxes = true;
lv_requirements.View = View.Details;
//add columns to list view
lv_requirements.Columns.Add("Name", 270);
lv_requirements.Columns.Add("Type", 150);
lv_requirements.Columns.Add("Status", 100);
lv_requirements.Columns.Add("Current Version", 80);
lv_requirements.Columns.Add("Latest Version", 80);
```

And I add items to list as follows:

```
String[] itemContent = new String[5];
itemContent[0] = Name;
itemContent[1] = Type;
itemContent[2] = ID;
itemContent[3] = CurrentVersionNumber;
itemContent[4] = LatestVersionNumber;

ListViewItem add = new ListViewItem(itemContent);
add.Tag = handle;

//Add image to list item
add.ImageIndex = item.DisplayImageIndex;
lv_requirements.SmallImageList = icons;
lv_requirements.Items.Add(add);
```

What I would like to modify is:

```
object[] itemContent = new object[5];
itemContent[4] = new ComboBox([AllLaterVersions]);
```

But as I understand it there is no way to initiate a new ListViewItem with anything but Strings. Is there someway for me to either have a ComboBox with all versions or if not possible, at least have an inputable text field in that column instead where the user can input the version of his/her desire.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, ListView by design is intended for String Literals as its item. There might be some hack to actually do something similar as you want but I am pretty certain it won't be a very elegant solution.

So my advice, dump ListView and use DataGridView, with very little effort you can make the GridView look quite similar to ListView and you can add a dropdown and what not...

Answer (score 0):

you could create an entity ViewModel with the values you need + 2 bool propreties that represent the user choice.

Then you can easily add DataTemplate to your ListView.

The DataTemplate will bind the checkbox (but i think using radio-buttons will be better choice here) to the properties of the VM.

```xml
<ListView>
 <ListView.View >
    <GridView >
        <!--  other columns you need-->
        <GridViewColumn Header="Versions" >
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsCheck="{Binding LatestVersion}"/>
                    <CheckBox IsCheck="{Binding CurrentVersion}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Tamir, however I believe you have misunderstood me slightly. _[AllLaterVersion]_ might be any number of versions and thus radiobuttons will not be a good idea for this. But thank you anyway!